# How to dynamically add buttons with a command argument for the OnClick Event

Tags: java, android

I am coming across an issue with dynamically creating buttons.  I have my text I am adding to the buttons, however I also have a command argument I want to send with it.  I want my dynamically created buttons to open up a new `Activity` and pass this argument via `Intent`. I am a .NET guy and this would be easily done with a `CommandParameter` off of the `Button`.

My question is, is this the following code best way to accomplish this task?  If so, how can I pass command arguments to the click event.  If not, what should be my approach?

```
int counter =0;

TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

while (counter< list.size())
{
    MyObj obj = list.get(counter);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(obj.getName());   
    // CommandParameter = obj.getId().toString();

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Context ctx = getApplicationContext(); 

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, TestScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("Id", "MyCommandParameter");
            startActivity(intent) ;
        }
    });

    layout.addView(b);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
intent.putExtra("Id", "MyCommandParameter");
```

with

```
intent.putExtra("Id", obj.getId().toString());
```

Also, you are better off using a foreach to iterate through the list rather than while loop.

Comment: I also had to add a final keyword for this to work, but this seems to solve my problem.  (it wouldnt compile with out it) Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.  I was unfamiliar with the final keyword, at least until I read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a child to a TableLayout you need to add a TableRow, And also You need to add the LayoutParams to button. Then add the button to the TableRow

```
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
               tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    .....
    .....
tr.addView(b);

layout.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```